# Pass parameters to javascript function of user control

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

I'm adding user control dynamically on my page.

**`MyPage.aspx`:**

```
MyControl cntl = (MyControl)Page.LoadControl("MyControl.ascx");
```

**The `MyControl.ascx` has a javascript function:**

```
function myfun(a, b)
{
    ....
}
```

I can pass parameters to `myfun` from code behind of `MyControl.ascx` like:

```
string script2 = String.Format("myfun({0},{1})", param1, param2);
this.Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "initialize control", script2, true);
```

Is it possible to call this javascript function from `MyPage.aspx`?

Comment: Check out [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2693601/how-to-call-javascript-function-from-c-sharp)

Comment: It doesn't work if you transfer your code in script2 inside MyPase.aspx?

Comment: Could you please clarify your requirement a bit more? As soon as the control is loaded in the page, the javascript function inside the user control is rendered and ready to use from the ASPX page. In .aspx if you try to invoke e.g. myfun(10,12), it will work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can call javascript dunction from mypage.aspx e.g. with a button

```
<asp:Button id="yourid" runat="server" OnClientClick="yourJavaScriptFunction("+a+","+b+")" />
```

Or anywhere in mypage.aspx.cs file

```
Response.Write("<script>yourJavaScriptFunction("+a+","+b+")</script>");
```